# Saas Application getting big now! Database Architecture question?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, saas

We have a SaaS application on AWS using a MySql RDS (database server).
Part of the SaaS app is storing documents for our users, currently this is being stored as long blobs and everything is running great. Its running on MultiAZ so redundancy/backups etc is not an issue unless we have to restore to our failover solution hosted on Azure which would be a nightmare! However, this would only be implemented upon AWS not existing any more so fairly unlikely.

However, we are going to be getting a lot (and I mean a lot) more users/customers on the system and the database size will be growing a ****load!

So, getting to my point, what's the general consensus amongst everyone with regards to storing files in the database as opposed to storing them in an S3 bucket for example?

Answer (score 1):

Your "files" are probably like "images".  That is, they never change, are never searched (via `WHERE`), and are only fed to users intact.

Given that, there is a slight preference for putting the "files" as "files" on servers that are designed for (primarily) read-only access.

You would, of course, have a URL or some other string in the database from which you could construct the method for detecting the "file".